# Vue SPA on IIS alias name issue

Tags: vue.js, iis, vuejs2, web-config, vue-router

I am deploying a Vue SPA application to IIS and im having some issues with the site alias. The site is deployed to the IIS Default Web Site, so it stays on port 80. Currently i have it named '**vue**' as the alias name for the site. This is all fine, but its going to be changed in the future and that means ill have to recompile the site for an alias name change.

***Can this all be handled on the web.config side instead of hard-coding `/vue` in my vue-router, vue.config***

The only way i can correctly get this to work is to first install the IIS urlrewrite2 plugin and setup the web.config in the dist folder.

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Handle History Mode" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/vue/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

router.js:

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history', // this will remove #/ from address bar.
  base: '/vue',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Main" */ '@/views/Main.vue'),
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Login" */ '@/views/Login.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      name: 'error',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "error" */ '@/views/404.vue')
    }
  ]
});
```

vue.confi.js:

```
module.exports = {
  productionSourceMap: false,
  transpileDependencies: [],
  publicPath: '/vue'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had what I think is a similar issue in managing address resolution for the callback address for my SPA authentication calls. So I don't have an exact solution for you, but hopefully the following suggestions are useful:

1) Code your app routes relative to root (i.e. instead of `base: '/vue`, use `base: '/'` in your router config. This simplifies things as now you have shifted all the resolution of the address to the web server, but now means you need a different IIS configuration.

The solution on the IIS side is to create a dedicated site for the SPA app in IIS, i.e. users will access your site by accessing `vue.mydomain.com` rather than `mydomain.com/vue`. This is achieved by setting a host name (can be anything, I just used 'vue' as an example) for the SPA site in IIS plus then ensuring your DNS server is configured to resolve `vue.domain.com` to the IP address of the IIS server.

This might feel like it makes the config on your dev machine complex and requires DNS changes for these machines as well. The trick is to use the hosts file on your dev/test machines to make the routing to the site work without the need for DNS changes.

2) In your SPA app, when referencing the SPA site's own address use `window.location.origin` wherever possible to work out an address relative to the source, rather than hard coding address paths. e.g. in my case I needed to define a callback path, which I did as follows `redirect_uri: window.location.origin + '/callback'`.

This is my go-to strategy and I like it because it ring-fences the SPA app from the rest of the website, simplifies the routing and means my dev/test/prod code all behaves exactly the same. If you absolutely need to use a relative path to access your site, then I suspect `window.location.origin` is still going to be your friend, but I can't give specific instructions on how to solve for your use case.

Whatever your approach you will still need IIS urlrewrite2 plugin to provide a re-route to handle using history mode in the router.